# Create json object dynamic in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have json :

```
{
   "fullName": "abc",
   "age": 19,
   ...
}
```

I want use Nodejs to add element in above json to object named Variables in below json

```
{
  "variables": {
    "fullName" : {
        "value" : "abc",
        "type" : "String"
    },
    "age": {
        "value" : 19,
        "type": "Number"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Please help me this case!

Comment: are you asking how to split your json and inject objects like type and value? or is it something else

Comment: @rand0m : I want to change json from old structure to new structure !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` with `.reduce()`

```js
let data = {
   "fullName": "abc",
   "age": 19,
}

let result = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
   a.variables[key] = { value, type: typeof value}
   return a;
}, { variables: {}})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can first `entries` of that object and then map it accordingly after that we convert that object using `Object.fromentries`. Here is an implementation:

```js
const obj = {  "fullName": "abc", "age": 19 };

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k,value])=>[k,{value, type:typeof value}]));

console.log({variable:result});
```

Comment: Thanks gorak! But I' using nodejs typescipt so it show error ```Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.ts(2339)```

Comment: @JavaDevBeginner Then one of solution with reduce will work. Or if your using `lodash` or `underscore`. You have an `fromPairs` method which will work instead of `Object.fromEntries`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for JSON.parse to get a struct from your file, then JSON.stringify to create a json from your struct ?

Comment: Yes. I want to change json from old structure to new structure !